# Accessing user information via `IHttpContextAccessor` from project created with `dotnet new react -au Individual`?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4

#### Background

I've been following the [documentation for using IdentityServer4 with single-page-applications on ASP.NET-Core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and as such created a project via the `dotnet new react -au Individual` command.
This creates a project which uses the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer` NuGet package.

So far it's been really great and it got token-based authentication for my ReactJS application working without any pain!
From my ReactJS application, I can access the user information populated by the [oidc-client npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oidc-client) such as the username.

Also, calls to my Web APIs with the `[Authorize]` attribute work as expected: only calls with a valid JWT access token in the request header have access to the API.

#### Problem

I'm now trying to access basic user information (specifically username) from within a GraphQL mutation resolver via an injected `IHttpContextAccessor` but the only user information I can find are the following claims under `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User`:

```
nbf: 1600012246
exp: 1600015846
iss: https://localhost:44348
aud: MySite.HostAPI
client_id: MySite
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: (actual user GUID here)
auth_time: 1600012235
http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider: local
scope: openid
scope: profile
scope: MySite.HostAPI
http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences: pwd
```

The same issue happens for Web API controllers as well.

#### Details

`MySite` is the namespace of my solution and is also what I have defined as a client in my `appsettings.json` file:

```json
{
    "IdentityServer": {
        "Clients": {
            "MySite": {
                "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My web application project's name is `MySite.Host` so `MySite.HostAPI` the name of the resource and scope that are automatically generated by calling [`AuthenticationBuilder.AddIdentityServerJwt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#addidentityserverjwt).

> ... this method registers an <<ApplicationName>>API API resource with IdentityServer with a default scope of <<ApplicationName>>API and configures the JWT Bearer token middleware to validate tokens issued by IdentityServer for the app.

#### Research

According to a few answers on Stack Overflow, adding `IdentityResources.Profile()` resource via `IIdentityServerBuilder.AddInMemoryIdentityResources()` should do the trick but it looks like it's already available via the claims I posted above (`scope: profile`).
I nevertheless tried it but the result is that the authentication flow becomes broken: the redirect to the login page does not work.

All of the answers I've found also make a reference to a Config class like in [this demo file](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Config.cs) which holds configurations that are mainly fed to `IIdentityServerBuild.AddInMemory...()` methods.
However, it seems that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer` does most of this in its implementation and instead offers [extendable builders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.apiauthorization.identityserver?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to use.

From the IdentityServer documentation, I don't believe I need to add a Client because the access token already exists. The client ReactJS application uses the `access_token` from `oidc-client` to make authorised calls to my Web APIs.

It also doesn't appear like I need to add a Resource or Scope for the username information because I believe these already exist and are named `profile`. More to this point is that the [documentation for `"IdentityServerSPA"` client profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#application-profiles) states that:

> The set of scopes includes the openid, profile, and every scope defined for the APIs in the app.

I also looked at implementing `IProfileService` because [according to the documentation this is where additional claims are populated](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/reference/profileservice.html). The default implementation is currently being used to populate the claims that are being requested by the `ProfileDataRequestContext.RequestedClaimTypes` object and this mechanism already works because this is how the ReactJS client code receives them. This means that when I'm trying to get the user claims from ASP.NET-Core Identity, it's not properly populating `ProfileDataRequestContext.RequestedClaimTypes` or perhaps not even calling `IProfileServices.GetProfileDataAsync` at all.

#### Question

Considering that my project uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer`, how can I view the username from my ASP.NET-Core C# code, preferably with `IHttpContextAccessor`?

Comment: Not an answer since I haven't touched IdSrv4 for quite some time, but: stuff like username are user claims. You need to create these user claims, assign values to these for each user (many-many relationship in IdSrv4 DB), and then the client must specifically request these user claims when authorizing (and so the client must be allowed to request these claims, this last step can be considered "done" if you say those claims belong to the `profile` scope)

Comment: Would that be done in an implementation of `IProfileService`? [According to the documentation](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/reference/profileservice.html), this is where I would add additional claims. I thought I wouldn't have to do that because I thought username was basic but it looks like I was wrong. I'm not really sure how to implement `IsActiveAsync`. Would my implementation override the default one that was setup by the scaffolding and are there security risks with that?

Comment: Remember: IdSrv4 is an open source framework, you can always look at the source code if you're doubtful. The default profile is https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/Default/DefaultProfileService.cs and ASP.NET Core Identity's is https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/AspNetIdentity/src/ProfileService.cs - you can easily say that `IsActiveAsync` returns always `true` in both versions, you probably want to change that

Comment: Thanks for that @CamiloTerevinto! Interesting. I also found an alternative and posted it as an answer below but your solution is better. Do you mind posting it as an answer? If not I'll go ahead and add a second answer once I write a toy implementation of `IProfileService`.

Comment: While trying to implement `IProfileServices` it I ran into an issue. The default implementation is currently being used to populate the claims that are being requested by the `ProfileDataRequestContext.RequestedClaimTypes` object and this mechanism already works because this is how the ReactJS client code receives them. This means that when I'm trying to get the user claims from ASP.NET-Core Identity, it's not properly populating `ProfileDataRequestContext.RequestedClaimTypes` or perhaps not even calling `IProfileServices.GetProfileDataAsync` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to extend the default claims requested by IdentityServer with your custom ones. Unfortunately, since you're using the minimalistic IdentityServer implementation by Microsoft, the correct way of making the client request the claims isn't easy to find. However, assuming you have only one application (as per the template), you could say that the client *always* wants some custom claims.

**Very important first step:**
Given your custom `IProfileService` called, say, `CustomProfileService`, after these lines:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

you **have to** get rid of the implementation used in the scaffolded template, and use your own:

```
services.RemoveAll<IProfileService>();
services.AddScoped<IProfileService, CustomProfileService>();
```

Next, the actual implementation of the custom `IProfileService` isn't really hard if you start from Microsoft's version:

```
public class CustomProfileService : IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity.ProfileService<ApplicationUser>
{
    public CustomProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory) : base(userManager, claimsFactory)
    {
    }

    public CustomProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory,
        ILogger<ProfileService<ApplicationUser>> logger) : base(userManager, claimsFactory, logger)
    {
    }

    public override async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        string sub = context.Subject?.GetSubjectId();

        if (sub == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No sub claim present");
        }

        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        if (user == null)
        {
            Logger?.LogWarning("No user found matching subject Id: {0}", sub);
            return;
        }

        var claimsPrincipal = await ClaimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
        if (claimsPrincipal == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("ClaimsFactory failed to create a principal");
        }

        context.AddRequestedClaims(claimsPrincipal.Claims);
    }
}
```

With those two steps in place, you can start tweaking `CustomProfileService`'s `GetProfileDataAsync` according to your needs. Notice that ASP.NET Core Identity by default already has the email and the username (you can see these in the `claimsPrincipal` variable) claims, so it's a matter of "requesting" them:

```
// ....
// also notice that the default client in the template does not request any claim type,
// so you could just override if you want
context.RequestedClaimTypes = context.RequestedClaimTypes.Union(new[] { "email" }).ToList();
context.AddRequestedClaims(claimsPrincipal.Claims);
```

And if you want to add custom data, for example, the users first and last name:

```
// ....
context.RequestedClaimTypes = context.RequestedClaimTypes.Union(new[] { "first_name", "last_name" }).ToList();
context.AddRequestedClaims(claimsPrincipal.Claims);
context.AddRequestedClaims(new[] 
{ 
    new Claim("first_name", user.FirstName),
    new Claim("last_name", user.LastName),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

User information can be retrieved via the scoped `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` service which is set up by the project template. The users's claims contains `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"` (`ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`) whose value is the user identifier. `UserManager<>.FindByIdAsync()` can then be used to retrieve the `ApplicationUser` associated with the user and which contains additional user information.

**Note** that this contacts the user store each time it's invoked. A better solution would be to have the extra user information in the claims.

First, explicitly add the `IHttpContextAccessor` service if you haven't already by calling `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`

From within an arbitrary singleton service:

```cs
public class MyService
{
    public MyService(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider
    )
    {
        var nameIdentifier = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

        using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(nameIdentifier);
            // Can access user.UserName.
        }
    }
}
```

`UserManager<ApplicationUser>` can be accessed directly within Razor pages and Controllers because these are already scoped.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you're always contacting the database, and you can only have the value in the server-side, while if you had the user's name in a claim, you'd already have the value in memory and in clients (provided you allowed each client access to such claim)